# var_dump shows data but echo says Undefined index - At a loss

Tags: php, mysql

I've got two queries going on, one is working fine... Echos all the right column values. The second one shows all the data var_dump but keeps showing Undefined Index. I don't understand what I've done wrong.

I tried to make an array to define the index via the suggestion of a developer but that gave me zero results

```
$navpage = array();
$navpage['splash_id']='';
```

etc but that results in the empty space obviously... I don't know why this was the solution I was led to.

> Error code says : Notice: Undefined index: splash_id in...

I know there are so many questions like this and most of them are talking about email forms they are working on, while I am just trying to output data from the database.

Here is my query file arts.php

```
<?php
require 'scripts/start.php';
$pages = $db->query("SELECT article_id, department, title, article_link, shortdesc, img_meta, live FROM content WHERE department='Arts' AND live='Yes'
")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$navpage = $db->query("SELECT splash_id, page, live, big_message, img1, text1, link1, expdate FROM splash WHERE page='arts' AND live='Yes'
")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  require VIEW_ROOT . '/artpages.php';
?>
```

The page where I echo things like column - text1

```
<?php require VIEW_ROOT . '/department/arts_header.php';

?>
<div id="major">
<div id="so" class="mainimage">
<div class="mainimage"><img src="cms_img/header/<?php echo $navpage['img1']?>" class="splashimage"></div>
</div>
<div id="contentbox">
<div id="middle"><div id="articleheadline" class="titlefont"><?php echo $navpage['text1']?></div>
  <?php if (empty($pages)): ?>
  <p class="textfont">Sorry, there are no articles on this page.</p>
<?php else: ?>
  <?php foreach($pages as $page): ?>
    <div class="article_container">
      <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/artsarticle.php?page=<?php echo $page['article_link']?>"><div class="article_promo"><img src="cms_img/<?php echo escape($page['img_meta']) ?>"class="promofit"></div></a>
      <div class="article_title"><span class="article_title_font"><?php echo $page['title']?></span></div>
      <div class="article_desc"><span class="article_desc_font"><?php echo $page['shortdesc']?></span></div>
    </div><?php endforeach; ?>

  <?php endif; ?>
</div></div></div></div>
<?php
require VIEW_ROOT . '/templates/footer.php';
?>
```

I expect echos of `$navpage` to fill in like `$page` does.

Comment: where's the code `$navpage['splash_id']` used?

Comment: maybe there are no results for he query to return

Comment: I just used that as an example, my bad... I use $navpage['img1] and $navpage[text1] on Div class main image and Article Headline respectively

Comment: That's just it when I do var_dump it shows me this.... array(1) { [0]=> array(8) { ["splash_id"]=> string(1) "4" ["page"]=> string(4) "arts" ["live"]=> string(3) "Yes" ["big_message"]=> string(17) "ART IS ALL AROUND" ["img1"]=> string(15) "tna07banner.jpg" ["text1"]=> string(28) "art is this thing right here" ["link1"]=> string(11) "tnamag.com/" ["expdate"]=> string(10) "2019-10-10" } }

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Fetch all get a multiple array result so you need to use foreach loop like you did in $pages or use the following code below to fetch only a single array.

```
$dbh = new PDO("SELECT article_id, department, title, article_link, shortdesc, img_meta, live FROM content WHERE department='Arts' AND live='Yes'"); 
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE id=4 LIMIT 1"); 
$stmt->execute(); 
$navpage= $stmt->fetch();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you use `->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`. Its return array of item `navpage`

So you must to code `$navpage[0]['img1']` and `$navpage[0]['text1']`

Notice check `!empty($navpage)` before use `$navpage[0]`

Comment: I used fetchAll for $page as well but that doesn't seem to have an issue. That is what's confusing to me most.

Comment: with `$pages` you use foreach to print each item `$page`. That's a array of items

Comment: I see. Would you kindly explain where I do the $navpage[0]['img1']? Is it on top of the query? Does it matter?

Comment: $navpage = $db->query("SELECT splash_id, page, live, big_message, img1, text1, link1, expdate FROM splash WHERE page='arts' AND live='Yes'
")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
$navpage [0]['splash_id'];
$navpage [0]['page'];
$navpage [0]['live'];
$navpage [0]['big_message'];
$navpage [0]['img1'];
$navpage [0]['text1'];
$navpage [0]['link1'];
$navpage [0]['expdate'];

Comment: Ex: `<img src="cms_img/header/<?php echo $navpage['img1']?>" class="splashimage">` you change to `<img src="cms_img/header/<?php echo $navpage[0]['img1']?>" class="splashimage">`